# How to find disk usage more than 70% and find largest in there with one script?

Tags: shell-script, disk-usage

I have a problem, how to find disk usage more than 70%, can be found forwarded by finding the largest file in them, then displaying it?

Please help me with the shell script, thanks for the attention.

I have tried a script, but I have not found exactly what I meant, what is needed is only to find the largest file from the filesystem which has xx% utilization. Can it be combined into one script? So if there is a fileusage of more than xx% then look for and display the largest file with the head -10?

i have tried with script:

```
$ df -Ph | awk '+$5>=10 || $1=="Filesystem"' && du -h | sort -nr | head -10 || echo Fail usage is less from 10%
```

But when finding disk usage more than xx% should not show the largest file search, only shows echo "fileusage less from xx% ! "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first part

```
df -Ph | awk '+$5>=10 || $1=="Filesystem"'
```

always return true.

```
if df -Ph | awk '+$5<=10 || $1=="Filesystem" { if ( +$5<=10) exit(1) ; else exit(0) }'
then du -h | sort -nr | head -10 
else  echo Fail usage is less from 10%
fi
```

you can one-line it by folding the line and including `';'` in place of end of line.

Comment: I have tired and the script reads correctly !
Thanks veri much Sir, Awesome, hopefully your career will be better because it helps your fellow human beings. +1